# Отчет в C# через Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystalreport

Делаю отчет в Crystal Report в C#. В документах есть продукты, продукты лучше выводить через субрепорт который будет выводить список продуктов или вытягивать как то деталью?

Структура отчета:

1. Шапка документа (дата, номер и так дальше)
2. Список продуктов к документу. (таблица - название продукта, кол-во, цена)

Смотрел разные видео и читал, в основном все для простых отчетов, но не находил примеров для отчетов с доп. информацией, как с продуктами. Подскажите кто знает, как правильно это все сделать. Есть опыт в Fast Report, там делал через доп. деталь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно в отчете показать простую связь Master->1_Detail (один блок деталей), то делаю запрос с обычным join-ом, потом в отчете группирую по мастер данным.

Если в блоке деталей надо показать несколько типов данных, то эти типы выделяю в субрепорты.